# Android 4.4 Nexus 4 — rild.* section is missing in build.prop

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-4

On Nexus S (2.3 vanilla):

```
$ adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep rild
rild.libpath=/vendor/lib/libsec-ril.so
rild.libargs=-d /dev/ttyS0
```

On Nexus 4 (4.4 vanilla):

```
$ adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep rild
$
```

This prop present on all my Android phones: Samsung Galaxy Trend (4.1), Alcatel One Touch Pixie (2.3), Motorola Moto G (4.3), but is missing on Nexus 4.

Full build.prop:

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=KOT49H
ro.build.display.id=KOT49H
ro.build.version.incremental=937116
ro.build.version.sdk=19
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=4.4.2
ro.build.date=Wed Dec  4 23:40:01 UTC 2013
ro.build.date.utc=1386200401
ro.build.type=user
ro.build.user=android-build
ro.build.host=kpfj3.cbf.corp.google.com
ro.build.tags=release-keys
ro.product.model=Nexus 4
ro.product.brand=google
ro.product.name=occam
ro.product.device=mako
ro.product.board=MAKO
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=LGE
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=US
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.board.platform=msm8960
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=mako
# Do not try to parse ro.build.description or .fingerprint
ro.build.description=occam-user 4.4.2 KOT49H 937116 release-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=google/occam/mako:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys
ro.build.characteristics=nosdcard
# end build properties

#
# ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
ro.config.ringtone=Themos.ogg
ro.config.notification_sound=Tejat.ogg
ro.config.alarm_alert=Oxygen.ogg
ro.com.android.dateformat=MM-dd-yyyy
ro.com.android.dataroaming=false
ro.url.legal=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html
ro.url.legal.android_privacy=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/privacy.html
ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-google
ro.carrier=unknown
ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist=GoogleGuest
ro.error.receiver.system.apps=com.google.android.gms
ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode=1
ro.opengles.version=196608
ro.sf.lcd_density=320
persist.audio.handset.mic.type=digital
persist.audio.dualmic.config=endfire
persist.audio.fluence.voicecall=true
persist.audio.handset.mic=dmic
persist.audio.fluence.mode=endfire
persist.audio.lowlatency.rec=false
af.resampler.quality=4
persist.radio.apm_sim_not_pwdn=1
ro.telephony.call_ring.multiple=0
persist.hwc.mdpcomp.enable=true
ro.qualcomm.bt.hci_transport=smd
telephony.lteOnCdmaDevice=0
drm.service.enabled=true
wifi.interface=wlan0
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=15
media.aac_51_output_enabled=true
debug.egl.recordable.rgba8888=1
ro.qc.sensors.wl_dis=true
ro.qualcomm.sensors.smd=true
dalvik.vm.heapstartsize=8m
dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=192m
dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m
dalvik.vm.heaptargetutilization=0.75
dalvik.vm.heapminfree=512k
dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree=8m
keyguard.no_require_sim=true
ro.facelock.black_timeout=400
ro.facelock.det_timeout=1500
ro.facelock.rec_timeout=2500
ro.facelock.lively_timeout=2500
ro.facelock.est_max_time=600
ro.facelock.use_intro_anim=false
persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib=libdvm.so
dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags=m=y
net.bt.name=Android
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt
```

The first question: is this "feature" of Nexus 4 only or whole Android 4.4?
The second question: how should I determine the radio interface location in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Android Phones regardless of Model or maker all have Build.Prop files. The Build.Prop File is used to determine phone functionality and setting information based on installed hardware and software. Carrier and Phone Build.Prop file will vary from phone to phone and could even further be augmented by the use of Custom Roms.

A Simple way to dump your build.prop file for a android device with ADB(Android Debug Bridge) would be to run the line below assuming you have ADB installed which it looks like you do.

```
adb shell getprop > "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\prop.txt"
```

This run in a command prompt will tell ADB to drop a file name prop.text file with the key/Value pair of the given device to your desktop. I like to use GetProp because it lays out your keys and values in a format that is easier to read.

As for your Question regarding the Radio Interface Location. You will have to be more specific. What Radio are you referring to? Cellular, Bluetooth or Wifi?

The answer in general could be that the maker of that phone did not create the key with a similar name and instead is using another format for identifying it. Also keep in mind that your older phones are running a older Android OS and the key your referring to could be a obsolete.

What key are you specifically looking for currently?